# .env File inaccessible after PHP/Laravel upgrade

Tags: php, laravel, .env

I recently upgraded my company's project PHP and Laravel versions:

PHP: 7.3.2 => 8.1.18
Laravel: 7.30.6 => 9.52.5

We are using PHP and Laravel for our backend, our frontend is Vue2.

We're using the PDO class to create a connection to BaanDB which is one of the DBs our company uses, it works with Informix driver and the class we use for that is PDO. It always worked before the upgrade to the new versions of Laravel/PHP. We use `env()` to get sensitive variables like passwords and hostname - also that how it worked for a long time for us.

Since the update, .env file became inaccessible through anywhere in the code, so lines like: `$pdo = new \PDO(env('BAAN_DB_DSN_PDO'), env('BAAN_DB_USERNAME_PDO'), env('BAAN_DB_PASSWORD_PDO'), $options);` which are taking values of important data from the .env file raised an error which looks like: `PDO::__construct(): Argument #1 ($dsn) must be a valid data source name` which basically means the .env file couldn't be read and recieved a null (tested in debugger).

I did found a solution for the problem which also regarded that the issue is happening after upgrading Laravel version.

The solution was to run the following 2 commands: `php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan config:clear`.

This fixed the issue, but raised another one. The issue happens again if you reset apache on the server, it also happens again after certain different changes to the system. Do I have to write the 2 commands again after every change caused to the server? this might interfere with the regular work we had, Is there some other solution which is more globally?

**Edit:** After trying the solution @Refilon suggested in the answer, The first error was gone and I received the following error in my network tab: `SQLSTATE=HY000, SQLDriverConnect: -11041 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Unspecified System Error =  -11041`. I'll also mention we installed a new Informix driver on the server: ibm.csdk.4.50.FC1.LNX. It was tested by my manager and seemed to work. But perhaps the correct syntax was changed? Would appreciate any solution regarding that error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you get from `env('BAAN_DB_DSN_PDO')` then?

Comment: try with `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I get null.

Comment: @BhargavChudasama I tried, lets see if it will happen again in a few minutes I'll let you know. Anyways, I also noticed now that the issue is indeed fixed after the 2 first commands I wrote in the original post, but it repeats itself some minutes later on. Not sure what is the trigger, maybe something some other developer does on the server or maybe something a user does on the website.

Comment: @BhargavChudasama Yep, the same issue persists and happened again. The commands seems to solve the problem for several minutes and then I get the same error again.

Comment: maybe it happened because you saved to cache and config data. so for this, you need to remove those data whenever you made any changes in your config or cache file. so try with this command `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: @BhargavChudasama Okay that seemed to solve the problem for the moment, let me check if it will repeat itself again in a few minutes, will let you know. thank you.

Comment: @BhargavChudasama Ye as expected, the issue happened again. after about 45 minutes the same error appeared and .env file is again inaccessible.

Comment: `$pdo = new \PDO(env('BAAN_DB_DSN_PDO')` - that does not look like you are using Laravel properly. Why do you use the PDO class and `env()`?

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase, I'm using the PDO class to create a connection to BaanDB which is one of the DBs our company uses, it works through Informix and the class we use for that is PDO. It always worked before the upgrade to the new versions of laravel/php. And we use `env()` to get sensitive variables like passwords and hostname - also that how it worked for a long time for us. Now, I understood from the answer below that I'm suppose to do it through `config` which is what I'm testing currently.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would like to do this as Laravel can handle this for you. But here's my answer.

Don't use the `env()` function in your code. Store the `env()` variables in a php file in the config folder and then use it in your code like so: config('filename.variable_name');

Example:

Create a new config file. For example: config/db.php

```
<?php

return [
    'db' => env('BAAN_DB_DSN_PDO'),
    'username' => env('BAAN_DB_USERNAME_PDO'),
    'password' => env('BAAN_DB_PASSWORD_PDO'),
];
```

Then in your code:

```
$pdo = new \PDO(config('db.db'), config('db.username'), config('db.password'), $options);
```

Comment: Okay, I tried what you suggested and now the error had been changed, locally that seemed to worked good but on the server I received the following error in the network tab: `SQLSTATE=HY000, SQLDriverConnect: -11041 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Unspecified System Error =  -11041`. Any Idea how to solve that? p.s. - The related Informix driver is installed on the server and was tested by my manager.

Comment: Also, maybe the correct Syntax was changed for the new driver? The new driver we installed is: ibm.csdk.4.50.FC1.LNX

Comment: @GadyEilat I don't think this is a laravel issue. But appears to be a misconfiguration on your server.

Comment: We didn't really change the configurations files such as odbc.ini, php.ini, odbcinst.ini after the update. Where can I find a proper documentation regarding any changes that should be done to those files after the driver update? technically everything else worked fine after the php/laravel upgrade except for that .env file and the pdo odbc issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The issue was that we needed to export the environment variables to Apache httpd.

There is a file in the linux server within the path: /etc/sysconfig/httpd.

We had to add the following lines to the file: `LANG=C`
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/IBM/informix/lib/:/opt/IBM/informix/lib/cli:/opt/IBM/informix/lib/esql`
`INFORMIXDIR=/opt/IBM/informix`
`ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini`

Somehow everything worked fine in earlier versions of PHP/Laravel without these lines.
After adding these lines we restarted Apache and the PDO connection was established successfully.

P.S.: @Refilon solved the first error of `PDO::__construct(): Argument #1 ($dsn) must be a valid data source name`. So thanks for that too!

Comment: Glad you solved it, but this was not the answer to the original question. My answer was the correct one for the original question and this answer is the correct one for an issue you had after ;) So imho you marked the wrong answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Seems legit. You got the mark :)